# Why does this jQuery replace() not work in an <a tag, though I got it to work in a <p tag?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

The code is located @ http://www.iluvtrees.org/ and we are trying to remove a colon (:) with...

```
jQuery('#events-calendar-list li a').text(this.text().replace(':', ''));
```

I am doing this remotely and was able to get a simpler string to work using this script. The difficulty in the selector, our html looks like so...

```
...
<ul id="events-calendar-list">
<li id="events-calendar-list-630" title="
<strong>Title: </strong><b>#62 It's Little Things
</b><br />Check your fuel consumption and tire pressure to make sure your car is running as efficiently as possible.
<br /><strong>Start Time: </strong>12:00 am<br /><strong>End Time: </strong>12:00 am<br />">events=Object { mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
<a href="http://www.iluvtrees.org/">
<strong style="display: none;">Thu 3/14/2013</strong>
: //<- - - this is what we are trying to remove - - - -
<b>#62 It's Little Things</b>
<br>
</a>
...
```

I don't have access to the PHP files at this time to remove from there.

Comment: Your title attribute is messed up. Is there some jQuery making it a tooltip?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a tag around that text so it's easy to target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the text nodes inside your anchor:

```
$('a').contents().filter(function(node) {
  return this.nodeType === 3; // filter text nodes
}).remove();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/epumaj/1/)

Comment: @popnoodles Comes straight from the Dark Lord himself ;-)

Comment: Wow! That is some sick stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Do it as below.

```
jQuery('#events-calendar-list li a').text(jQuery('#events-calendar-list li a').text().replace(':', ''));
```

In many **programming languages**, `this` **(or self)** is a keyword which can be used in **instance methods to refer to the object on which the currently executing method has been invoked.**

Comment: But won't this remove the formatting too? It's replacing the innerHTML with text. There's a `<strong>` in there. Admittedly it's hidden.

Comment: It works but then removes the colon in the nested 'display':'none', causing that to come back. Any idea on counting the colons?

Comment: @Shane what exactly you want to remove.

Comment: I gave you a couple +'s for the work, but ultimately the answer above for cleaning out the extra colons erased, though yours did work.

Answer (score 1):

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/WhGUM/)

Ok from the link you've given I'm assuming all the elements follow the same format.

So use this:

```
// .replace('</strong>: <b>','</strong><b>'); fiddle with the HTML, you can't use .text() here

jQuery('#events-calendar-list li a').html(jQuery('#events-calendar-list li a').html().replace('</strong>: <b>','</strong><b>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Test Website</title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                var x = $('a#test').text();
                                alert(x.replace(':', ''));
                        });
                </script>
        </head>
<body>

<ul id="events-calendar-list">
<li id="events-calendar-list-630" title="
<strong>Title: </strong><b>#62 It's Little Things
</b><br />Check your fuel consumption and tire pressure to make sure your car is running as efficiently as possible.
<br /><strong>Start Time: </strong>12:00 am<br /><strong>End Time: </strong>12:00 am<br />">events=Object { mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
<a id="test" href="http://www.iluvtrees.org/">
<strong style="display: none;">Thu 3/14/2013</strong>
: //<- - - this is what we are trying to remove - - - -
<b>#62 It's Little Things</b>
<br>
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha, no. Just a simple proof of concept.